# Im including <iterator> but get unknown type name 'iterator'

Tags: c++

I feel like this has to be an issue with namespace pollution, otherwise I dont know my compiler thinks iterator is an unknown type name

In a previous coding project I had a class with the exact same method declaration with no issues, which is why I dont understand why it doesnt work here.

The full error is

```
In file included from AlgoContainer.cc:1:
./AlgoContainer.h:14:3: fatal error: unknown type name 'iterator'
            iterator begin() const;
            ^
```

1 error generated.

Below is the code where the error is being thrown, in my header file

```
#ifndef AlgoContainer_H_INCLUDED
#define AlgoContainer_H_INCLUDED

#include <vector>
#include "Task.h"
#include <iterator>


class AlgoContainer{
    public:
        AlgoContainer() = default;
        void addTask(const Task);
        ~AlgoContainer();
        iterator begin() const;
        iterator end() const;

    private:
        std::vector<Task> allTasks;
        void sort();
    
 };

 #endif /*AlgoContainer_H_INCLUDED*/
```

If it is needed I will include the Task header file I am using and the AlgoContainer.cc files

AlgoContainer.cc

```
#include "AlgoContainer.h"

using namespaces std;

AlgoContainer::addTask(const Task newTask){
    this->allTasks.push_back(newTask);
}

AlgoContainer::~AlgoContainer(){
    //TODO delete without memory leak
}

AlgoContainer::iterator AlgoContainer::begin() const{
    return this->allTasks.begin();
}

AlgoContainer::iterator AlgoContainer::end() const{
    return this->allTasks.end();
}

void AlgoContainer::sort(){
    //TODO
}
```

Task.h

```
#ifndef Task_H_INCLUDED
#define Task_H_INCLUDED

class Task{
    public:
        Task(int pid, int arrivalTime, int burstDuration, int priority = 1);
        ~Task() = default;
        void alterBurstDuration(const int);
        int getPriority();
        int getPid();
        int getArrivalTime();
        int getBurstDuration();
        void continueWaiting();
        void taskComplete(const int);
    private:
        int pid;
        int arrivalTime;
        int burstDuration;
        int priority;
        int waitingTime;
        int finishedTime;
        enum state { waiting, running, finished};
        state taskState;
};

#endif /*TASK_H_INCLUDED*/
```

Additionally these are the parameters in which I am compiling if that helps

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -Wfatal-errors -Winit-self -Wshadow -Wcomment -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wold-style-cast -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -fno-diagnostics-show-option -std=c++14
```

Adding an std::iterator compiles with an error of

```
./AlgoContainer.h:14:8: fatal error: use of class template     'std::iterator' requires template
  arguments
            std::iterator begin() const;
```

Again weirdly in my past project I did not have the std:: before the iterator and had no issues, without using namespace std in the header

Comment: `std::iterator`

Comment: Thanks @AlexLarionov I should have mentioned I tried that but got a new error, Ill add that to the main

Comment: most probably you past project screwed up naming a bit, e.g. one of the past headers could do `using namespace std;`, which is dangerous, don't do that again (don't use `using namespace` in a header ever). The reason of the next error is that `std::iterator` needs a template argument, just as `std::vector` does.

Comment: What is `iterator` supposed to be? It can't be `std::iterator` from `<iterator>`, because it requires template arguments.

Comment: Thanks, but looking over my past code more closely I see what I did, but I wonder if it is considered bad practice? check my answer

Comment: Modify iterator to std::vector<Task>::iterator (or at least I think this is what you meant, because iterators are not standalone things (at least not in your case). You are returning an iterator to a vector of Tasks.

Comment: @AlexLarionov -- no, `std::iterator` is almost certainly not the right solution here. `std::iterator` is a template that provides a handful of typedef names. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by changing my header file to be

```
class AlgoContainer{
private:
    std::vector<Task> allTasks;
    void sort();
public:
    AlgoContainer() = default;
    void addTask(const Task);
    ~AlgoContainer();
    //CHANGE HERE
    using iterator = decltype(allTasks)::const_iterator;
    iterator begin() const;
    iterator end() const;

};
```

What is the consensus on whether this is frowned upon or not?

Comment: This is completely fine. The comment under the question saying this is frowned upon assumed your `iterator` was `std::iterator`, which it's not.